# How to select first item's sub-value from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which is described below:

```
dict={
      "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300}
      "Anna": "Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154}
      "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 100}
      "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96}
     }
```

I want to select or print first item's sub-value (i.e: `"Buy": 75`) of this nested dictionary.

If I am using this code:

```
print(trading_portfolio[(list(trading_portfolio.keys())[0])]["Buy"])
```

I'm getting error like this:

```
select first item from this nested dictionary
builtins.KeyError: "Buy"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code works fine for me but `next(iter(d.values()))["Buy"]` seems preferable. Never name a variable "dict"--it overwrites a builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code and if it not meet your expectation please ping me your exact query....

```
trading_portfolio={
  "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300},
  "Anna": {"Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154},
  "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 100},
  "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96}
 }
print(trading_portfolio[(list(trading_portfolio.keys())[0])]["Buy"])
```